# d3 arrow function and more than one argument

Tags: d3.js

Dear Stackoverflow community

I am still a d3 beginner. I am still not familiar with the the constructs in d3. I just try to use them but now I really want to break them down. Can anyone explain the part with arrow function and the ternary operator?

```
let svg d3.select("svg");
let my_data = [4,5,6];

update = svg.selectAll('rect')
  .data(my_data, (d,i) => d ? d:i);
```

How does the binding happen? and what is especially the result of this here:

`(d,i) => d ? d:i`?

I tried to search all the time but I could not find any matching answer.

Thank you very much

Comment: Can you share the source of this code?

Comment: @rioV8 Actually I want to know the keys for the rects and the keys for the elements of my_data

Comment: read the docs about SVG elements and basic JavaScript data structures